# How to share same instance of ViewModel between Activities using Koin DI?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am using `Koin` library in Kotlin for DI

Koin providing  `by viewmodel()` for get instance of ViewModel `by sharedViewModel()` to get same instance in fragments.

How can I get same instance of the ViewModel in  activities ? I didn't find any way to achieve this.

Comment: That is not supported by `ViewModel`.

Comment: This is possible by ViewModel Factory, but i didn't find any way to provide custom factory class in koin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research or discussion on architecture level and also report and issue github Koin,i found solution for this 
In this scenario,We should save that state/data into Repository which we need to share between multiple activities  not in the viewModel and   two or more different ViewModels  can access same state/data that are saved in single instance of repository

[image: see here]

Comment: This is not the correct answer, since ViewModel is able to be shared between views by definition. Google has been encouraging MVVM design exactly because with it we don't need do things like this answer propose. MVVM architecture is a declarative and reactive approach. Insert and restore data from database every time you need share it is much more costly for the application.  In my opinion this answer is about a MVP approach  not MVVM.  If you want something more imperative and bureaucratic consider moving your architecture to MVP or MVC.

Comment: You have probably solved your problem but this does not answer the question `How to share same instance of ViewModel between Activities using Koin DI?`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making the app a `ViewModelStoreOwner` and injecting the viewModels using as owner the app.
The code required would look like this

```
class App : Application(), ViewModelStoreOwner {
    private val mViewModelStore = ViewModelStore()

    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore {
        return mViewModelStore
    }
}
```

You can define some extensions to easily inject the viewModels

```
val Context.app: App
    get() = applicationContext as App

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Context.appViewModel(
    qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
    noinline state: BundleDefinition? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
): Lazy<T> {
    return lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        GlobalContext.get().getViewModel(qualifier, state, { ViewModelOwner.from(app, null) }, T::class, parameters)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.appViewModel(
    qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
    noinline state: BundleDefinition? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
): Lazy<T> {
    return lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        GlobalContext.get().getViewModel(qualifier, state, { ViewModelOwner.from(requireContext().app, null) }, T::class, parameters)
    }
}
```

You can then inject your viewModel like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val mAppViewModel: AppViewModel by appViewModel()
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to recreate the view model and if you decide to save the state between app restarts, you can easily make the app an `SavedStateRegistryOwner` as well and using the `SavedStateHandle` save/restore your state from inside the viewModel, being now bound to the process lifecycle.

Comment: how to override getViewModelStore() ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the missing override for `getViewModelStore()` in the answer.

Comment: ```Overriding this method is no longer supported and this method will be made
<code>final</code> in a future version of ComponentActivity.``` :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

you need to read more about `ViewModel` to understand it better.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

`ViewModel` is connected to your `Activity`

so you can share your Activities `ViewModel` only between his `Fragments` ,

that is what mean `sharedViewModel` in `koin`

`sharedViewModel` is the same if you use `ViewModel Factory` with same `context` .

sharing any data between `Activities` can be done via `Intent` , there is no another way in Android,

or you can keep some `static / global` data and share it between `Activities`

Comment: i know about ViewModel Pattern but  using ViewModel Custom Factory we can share Single viewmodel instance  with different activities so my question is there any way in koin to provide  custom ViewModel Factory
See here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory

Comment: @SahilArora ok . if you share some data between your activities , no matter how  you will do it, you will have following problems
1. it must be static
2. you will have memory leaks .
3. android created Intents, and any cases if you want to do customize data providing between activities you will meet static(global) and of course memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very very late but you can try this:
if you are extending a baseviewmodel, you need to declare the baseViewmodel as a `single` then in your respective  activity inject the BaseViewModel.
Practical example:

```
val dataModule = module {
    single { BaseViewModel(get(), get()) }
}
```

in your ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel(private val param: Repository,
                            param1: Pref,
                            param2: Engine) : BaseViewModel(param1, param2)
```

Then in your activity class

```
val baseViewModel: BaseViewModel by inject()
```

Hope this help someone.