# How can I share viewmodel from one screen to another screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am try to learning android jetpack compose, and I have simple app. In ScreenA I have a text field and when I click the button, I am save this data to firestore, and  when I come in ScreenB, I want to save city name also in firebase, but I am using one viewmodel, so how can save both text field data in the same place in firestore, I did not find any solution.

**ScreenA:**

```
    class ScreenAActivity : ComponentActivity() {



    private lateinit var  viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]


        setContent {
            ScreenA(viewModel)
        }
     }
   }

  @Composable
  fun ScreenA(

  viewModel : MyViewModel

  ) {

   val name = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

      OutlinedTextField(
            value = name.value,   
            onValueChange = { name.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "name") },
          
        )

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(40.dp)
                .height(20.dp),
            onClick = {

                focus.clearFocus(force = true)
                viewModel.onSignUp(
                    name.value.text,
                 
                )
                context.startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        context,
                        ScreenB::class.java
                    )
                )

                },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Red
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(60)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "OK"
             
             )
            )
        }

 }
```

**ScreenB:**

```
class ScreenBActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        ScreenB()
    }
 }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenB(

 ) {
val city = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

  OutlinedTextField(
        value = city.value,   
        onValueChange = { city.value = it },
        label = { Text(text = "city") },
      
    )

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(40.dp)
            .height(20.dp),
        onClick = {

            focus.clearFocus(force = true)
            viewModel.onSignUp(
                city.value.text,
             
            )
           

            },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.Red
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(60)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "OK"
         
         )
        )
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommendation is use a single activity and navigate through screens using [Navigation library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation).

After you've refactored your code to use the Navigation library, you can pass the previous back stack entry in order to get the same instance of the View Model.

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    ...
) { 
    composable("ScreenA") { backStackEntry ->
        val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(backStackEntry)
        ScreenA(viewModel)
    }
    composable("ScreenB") { backStackEntry ->
        val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(navController.previousBackStackEntry!!)
        ScreenB(viewModel)
    }
}
```

But if you really need to do this using activity, my suggestion is define a shared object between the view models. Something like:

```kotlin
object SharedSignInObject {
    fun signUp(name: String) {
        // do something
    }
    // other things you need to share...
}
```

and in your viewmodels you can use this object...

```kotlin
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    fun signUp(name: String) {
        SharedSignInObject.signUp(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx so much for ur answer,  I have to use intent for it now,  can you update ur answer for it? I cannot use navcontroller now.

Comment: In according to this answer (from Ian Lake, Googler Developer Advocate), it's not possible... If you really need this, it's better you use a another approach (via Intent extras, Shared Prefs, Database...)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845238/how-can-i-share-viewmodel-between-activities

Comment: Another suggestion is this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077784/how-to-share-same-instance-of-viewmodel-between-activities-using-koin-di

Comment: In Activity1, you use ViewModel1. In Activity2, you use ViewModel2. Both view models are sharing the same instance of `SharedSignInObject`. Therefore, everything you declare/save in `SharedSignInObject` will be available in both activities through the respective View Model. If you do `var x = 10` in `SharedSignInObject`, you can set/get this value from both view models... That's it... 
Unfortunately I can't be more clear than that...

Comment: how we can apply for this one, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71942247/13614484